# MongoDB writeConcern for production

Tags: mongodb, replication

My question may sound too general, but I'm ready to give any missing data.

We make something like a social network. In order to make read performance better and to ease the life of master instance, we've set

```
readPreference=secondaryPreferred
```

in our replicaSet. But with this, there's no guarantee that the data is written to secondary instances before you read from there, so we had to set

```
w=3
```

option.
So far, everything seems to be working but measurements on my local replicaSet show the following insert statistics.

```
Inserting 300 objects:
w=1 - 0.10s
w=3 - 1.31s
Insertion 5000 objects:
w=1 - 0.6s
w=3 - 14.6s
```

The question is, is this difference expected, or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The difference in performance is expected because w=3 means that you want to wait for acknowledgement that data was successfully replicated to at least two of your secondaries in addition to the acknowledgement from your primary (w=1).

For clarity, w = 1 simply means that you want an acknowledgement from the primary that an operation was completed. Any errors such as duplicate key errors or network errors that occur would be reported back as part of the acknowledgement if occurred.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/write-concern/

Refer to the link above, and you can see there are lower write concerns that let you trade safety for lower latency.

If you want higher level of durability or safety, then you might use j=1 to wait for an acknowledgement that your operation was written to the journal (allowing recovery from a failure). w > N increases safety by waiting for acknowledgement from > N replica members to ensure that your operation was successfully replicated to other members. **So to be clear, w > 1 isn't necessary to instruct the driver to write to the replicas.** If you decided to use w=N, be aware that you can get yourself in a bad situation if replica set members fail and fall below N. w = majority is a more flexible option.

Lastly, you may want to re-evaluate why you're reading from the secondaries. Secondaries are eventually consistent as MongoDB uses asynchronous replication. If you're expecting consistent reads, then it makes more sense to read from the primary. If your reason to read from the secondary is for scaling, you should consider sharding as this is the primary mechanism for scale-out. Distributing load on secondaries rarely improve scalability. Operations are replicated over to replicas, so you're not gaining much from a lower write load. Sometimes it makes sense to for distributing different types of workloads (may lead to better memory utilization). For instance, running a MR job on a secondary might make sense. Replica sets are primarily for high availability-- fault tolerance providing automatic fail-overs and network partition issues.

Comment: Thanks for response. Actually, we have sharded the database before doing this, there's no misunderstanding, we've enabled w=N for 2 reasons:
1. Lower the number of read requests to primary instance.
2. To have strong, not eventual, consistency.
From your response, the takeaway part is, consider reading from primary node if the operation requires strong consistency. :-)
Thanks.

Comment: Note on (2): Keep in mind that w=N doesn't change the fact that the secondaries are eventually consistent due to async replication. You would only get consistent reads on the secondary if you plan to read the same data that you just wrote with w=N. If this is you access pattern, consider findAndModify in place of doing the write and read sequence. This would ensure that this sequence of ops is atomic, and will perform faster than two separate operations.

Comment: You mean, if Thread A inserts a record and waits for acknowledgement from secondaries, another thread may get different results when reading from primary vs reading from secondary? 
It's somewhat OK for us, I think we can live with it for the time being.

Regarding findAndModify, it's not really easy to use it inside a webapp as it changes the logic of the code.

Comment: Yeah, my point is that reason #2 that you listed in your comments isn't a correct assumption. If you do w=3 on an insert, it doesn't mean that reading from a secondary will give you strong consistency.

Comment: Yeah, you're correct. It just gives the same effect if you use 1 thread or don't read the newly inserted data until fully acknowleged. Thanks a lot again.